# how to use sso just for some pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on

I have a web application. before I use sso for authentication. I put the code showed below in web.config page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="https://sso.***.***.***/login" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/Index.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
    </authentication>
```

It works well. Everyone go to that web need login first.
Now we need change to making some pages open to public. So people do not need login to access some pages, but some pages still need login ( use sso).
How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `<location>` and `<authorization>` sections of the web.config. If users are currently required to log in for all pages, I assume you have something like this:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?">
</authorization>
```

You can add `<location>` elements (these go outside the `<system.web>` section):

```
  <location path="publicpage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

You can add as many `<location>` elements as you want, and you can also target directories in the path attribute.

If you want to keep things a little cleaner for directories, you can add a web.config to a directory and add `<authorization>` and `<location>` elements to that web.config

Comment: [Here's an MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There is a link to the location element near the bottom of that page.

Comment: Hey Jason, you save my day!